# How to make a menu to remain visible after a parent / child has been clicked on

Tags: jquery

Hi thanks to this jsfiddle i've got mine working: http://jsfiddle.net/cesarvinas/ZQWe7/18

this is what i made:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kp4nd/5/

as you can see it adds a class and the removes.

if you click on MENU 1 - you see that menu 1 submenu item 1 is also active. But when i click on menu 1 submenu 2, submenu 1 is still active.

I've put the `<li><a href="#">MENU 1</a>` between `<span></span>` and that did the trick. But now my menu doesn't stay active...

And then i've got another problem. When you click on menu 2 the menu 1 submenu 1 is also then active, this should be then menu 2 submenu 1.

How can i fix it that it takes the right first-child item?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:  **[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/vqaHw/1/)**

```
$('ul li').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('currentParent');
  $(this).addClass('currentParent');
  $(this).find('ul li:first').addClass('currentChild').siblings().removeClass('currentChild').addClass('notSelected');
});

$('ul li ul li').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('currentChild').addClass('notSelected');
  $(this).removeClass('notSelected').addClass('currentChild');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Great!! it works... only one minor thing.

when i click Menu 1 - menu1 submenu item 1 is also active :) but when i click on menu 1 submenu item 3, and i go to menu 2 and click there and then go back to menu 1 Both submenu item 1 & 3 are active how i fix that?

Comment: hmm i'm having a problem with it now.. When i click on a parent page that one is active but when i click directly on a childpage within a different parent the parent page that was already active stays active... how can i fix that?

Comment: almost perfect :) ideally for example if you click on menu 2 - submenu 2 (that is then currentchild) if you then go to menu 1 - submenu 3 (then that one is active) and then when you hover over menu 2 submenu 1 should be active not submenu 2 How do i get that?